# Do I need to call through super class onCreate and onDestroy methods within an IntentService?

Tags: android, android-service, intentservice

I've derived a class from `IntentService` and I'm wondering if it is necessary to call through the super class `onCreate` and `onDestroy` methods when overriding these methods in my implementation as it happens when you override such methods in an `Activity`.. If it is necessary, do these invocation need to be the first thing we do in the overriding method? In the `Activity` documentation they are very clear about that, while in the `Service` or `IntentService` docs I can't find anything specific.

Comment: just try it out -- Activity throws Exceptions if you don't call super.onCreate()..., so if it is necessary here, I'd expect the same from IntentService.

Answer (score 10):

> I'm wondering if it is necessary to call through the super class onCreate and onDestroy methods when overriding these methods in my implementation as it happens when you override such methods in an Activity.

Absolutely. Those methods are implemented on `IntentService`; if you fail to call through to them, your service simply will not work.

> If it is necessary, do these invocation need to be the first thing we do in the overriding method?

I would recommend calling `super.onCreate()` as the first thing that you do in your implementation of `onCreate()`, and calling `super.onDestroy()` as the last thing that you do in your implementation of `onDestroy()`.

Comment: I was thinking the same as you're suggesting about calling `onCreate()` at the beginning and `onDestroy()` at the end of the overriding methods.. my doubt was related to the `Activity` documentation, where they suggest to call through the superclass method for `onCreate()`, `onPause()`, `onDestroy()` etc at the beginning of the overriding methods, so I was wondering if it was the same for services... It makes me strange in an Activity to adhere to documentation directives by calling `onDestroy()` at the beginning of my own `Activity`'s `onDestroy()` method.. don't you think the same?

Comment: @GianniCostanzi: "where they suggest to call through the superclass method for onCreate(), onPause(), onDestroy() etc at the beginning of the overriding methods" -- I fail to see any such instructions in the `Activity` documentation.

Comment: Look at the remark after the code snippet in section [Implementing the lifecycle callbacks](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks): *Note: Your implementation of these lifecycle methods must always call the superclass implementation before doing any work, as shown in the examples above.*

Comment: @GianniCostanzi: They are welcome to their opinion. I used to do it that way too. I got yelled at, and switched to the approach in my answer. :-)

Comment: The approach in your answer seems more reasonable to me, since calling `destroy()` on the superclass before cleaning up the stuff in your own subclass seems like destroying the floor on which you are walking before leaving the floor carrying away your own things :)

Comment: @CommonsWare in this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/16152436/931982 .. he said    super.onDestroy() must be the first call of the onDestroy method if you override it... is it so??

Comment: @StinePike: I disagree with that other answer. In practice, so far, it has not mattered one way or another. However, suppose there is something that `Activity` cleans up in `onDestroy()` that your own `onDestroy()` code depends upon. In that case, you would *have* to do your logic first before chaining to the superclass, otherwise you will have problems.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I also knew that .. but that made me confused.

Comment: Does the same rule of calling `super` apply also for `Service` (not just `IntentService`)?